# Chrome/Other browsers changes the colors of a picture

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, colors

So I've been having this issue on my home desktop, where the colors of a picture could be completely different from the actual colors, when the browser renders it out. I am only having this issue on my desktop at home using Google Chrome, it works fine on my laptop and work PC, also using Google Chrome!

I've come to the conclusion that this is something driver related, I just don't know what to do about it .. Would anyone have any ideas?

Here's how it looks in Chrome:

[image]

And in Internet Explorer:

[image]

The box to the left is a `div` with `background-color:#093148;`, the image to the right should be fading to that color. But as you can see, that's different in Chrome :/ I have a GTX670 driver version 347.88 and I'm on Windows 7, if that matters :)

Comment: Chrome screencap looks like an alpha channel problem or a gamma problem.

Comment: What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If it is "gamma", it may be color management, try disabling or changing the color management profile "sRGB; adobe RGB etc" when saving out the source image and then see if the result is any different when composited by chrome.

Comment: Why thank you! Fixed it, just weird how it's only on my desktop though

Comment: Color management support is frequently enabled and disabled per release. They break it they fix it, then re-break it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chrome screencap looks like an alpha channel problem or a gamma problem.

If it is "gamma", it may be color management, try disabling or changing the color management profile "sRGB; adobe RGB etc" when saving out the source image and then see if the result is any different when composited by chrome.

Browser embedded color management support is frequently enabled and disabled per release. They break it, they fix it, then re-break it.